# Save data from biometric finger device into database - attendance system

Tags: fingerprint, biometrics, time-and-attendance

I want to develop attendance system for office where employees give the attendance using finger print, I need to buy bio metric device, and i want to save the attendance data only in my cloud database. No other person should be able to access that data. How do I capture the user that has clocked in via the attendance and save their data in database.

Which is a suitable device for this?  Any biometric device that provides call back to my url with the user details when attendance is recorded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[CAMS](http://www.etscouncil.com/login?mailerResponse=true&orn=stackoverflow&ts=04/08/2017&ornr=%22https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42625942/save-data-from-biometric-finger-device-into-database-attendance-system%22&tpc=CAMS&it=CAMS-website&learnref=http://camsunit.com) supports the Web API for the the biometric machines which can be integrated with a website or any internet web application. It provides RESTful APIs and Callback API for various operations with biometric machines. You can get the detailed information from [biometric Web API](http://camsunit.com/application/biometric-web-api.html).

According to CAMS, An URL should be submitted along with the machine. Once the URL is associated, whenever the attendance gets registered, the submitted URL will be called automatically. Now user can maintain the records in their database and use them for generating reports.

The URL will be called whenever a new attendance gets registered with the following parameters in POST

- *stgid* - service tag id, means machine id,
- *userid* - numerical user id
- *att_time* - timestamp of attendance date & time
- *att_type* - i/o ==> i for check in, and o for check out

The URL should return "ok" in the response once it processed the attendance record. If "ok" is not returned, the URL will be called every time again and again with the same attendance records. If the URL's web server is down, the attendance records will try to reach the URL in every 30 seconds.

Comment: CAMS with API is still in development phase. I have just talked to them.
Any other devices with the same kind of functionality?

Comment: Hello Ketan, The API details mentioned in the answer is available in market for last 4 years. Lots of video with odoo integration, cloud integration and etc., are available in the youtube too.

Comment: Hello Ketan, http://camsunit.com/application/html-based-fingerprint-scanner-for-website-authentication-and-attendance.html is the API documentation for the fingerprint scanner integration with web application from CAMS